# Achieving simple tasks with vue (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Ive recently started learning vue.js (Coming from angular 2+), Ive watched a few tutorials and it all seemed to go swimmingly.

As always after ive finished doing the tutorials, I create a little app for myself just to ensure I know what im doing. But I seem to be really stuggling with Vue.

So far the app is very simple. A user posts a story, The story has comments.... simple as that

I got to the point where I wanted the user to be able to edit there comment, But It seems I cannot work out how to do this. I would like it so that when the user clicks the edit button the comment changes to a textarea or an input of some kind.

At this point I have not used to vue in the project at all. All the pages are rendered with blade.

Im trying to get my head round how you are meant to use it? So I have the following questions

1. Are you meant to use multiple vue components, Loop in blade and create a  on each iteration?

   ```
   <div id="app">
       @foreach($comments as $comment)
           <comment {Stuff passed in}></comment>
       @endforeach
   </div>
   ```
2. Are you meant to have that one vue "app" that gets the data from the api and loop them within the vue component?

   ```
       const comments = new Vue({
           el: '#comments#'
       })
   ```
3. As all the site is a multipage application (Dont want to go down the SPA route) and lets say I now have a products page, The product has a list of attributes (Pretty much the same as comments). Do I create another vue app?

   ```
   const comments = new Vue({
       el: '#comments',
   });


   const productThings = new Vue({
       el: '#productThings'
   })
   ```

   4. If I want to sections on a page controlled by vue (Lets say the comment section and another interactive section) Would this have to be 2 vue "apps" like in the above code example, One that is "comments" and one that is "somethingelse" or would the whole page have to be one big vue component.

      `````
      // Comment loop, How ever this gets handled with vue 
      // Some other content 
      // Another place I need it to be interactive````
      `````

This seems very complicated just to acheive simple tasks, Also seems as if it would get out of control very quickly (I could only imagine coming back to this after 6 months and trying to work out what was going on).

You can see how confused I am with it all, The more I read the more confused I seem to get.

Comment: The idea Vue is not capable of replacing Angular is a preconception. I've worked with both on a daily basis for years. The main difference between them is that Vue's syntax is way less verbose and a lot more transparent. It will take you probably 1 month to feel at ease in it but chances are you won't want to go back. For me, the biggest gain Vue has is, hands down: not rerendering the whole application after each change. This alone cuts down development time in half, at least. Also tests are easier in Jest than in Jasmine, IMHO.

Comment: Oh, and the other major gain is Vuex. Sure enough I was able to do store-like patterns in Angular as well but, because they're custom, I end up writing more code than in Vuex for achieving the same thing: one source of truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue is used to create fully fledged SPA web applications but can only be used as a drop-in without build process for simpler use cases. Usually you would integrated Vue Router to create a multi-page experience, but you can also just define single components and mount them on an element. In your case, with the mixing of PHP and Vue, I would suggest going for the way without build process and drop-in components.

Vue is a JavaScript framework with static templates. So, you should not generate dynamic templates and then pass them to Vue, but rather define static templates and then pass only the data to Vue. You can e.g. fetch the data via Ajax in a JSON format and then process this data to e.g. render a list of comments.

If you go for using Vue as a drop-in without routing, you need to mount two separate Vue instances on their respective pages. You can of course reuse parts of these components. Keep in mind, that you cannot share data between these instances (one of the benefits of using a SPA). You could however share the data via LocalStorage/SessionStorage/IndexedDB.

One common way to access the data is via a REST API (via Ajax/fetch). You would provide the data in a proper format (usually JSON) behind a HTTP REST interface. Then, Vue fetches the data (see also [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) for easy data fetching) and then uses it to build up the components. Another approach (less nice) is to just render the data with your server-side programming language and put it into a JavaScript variable, so, that you have access to the data on runtime.

Here is a basic example. Keep in mind that binding a value from a property is an anti-pattern and therefore I did not bind the comment text in a two-way manner. I have also hard-coded the comment data and do not fetch it from remote.

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('comment', {
  data () {
    return {
      commentAsInput: false
    };
  },
  props: {
    commentObject: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <a href="#" @click="commentAsInput = !commentAsInput" v-if="!commentAsInput">
      {{ commentObject.text }}
    </a>
    <textarea :value="commentObject.text" v-if="commentAsInput" />
  </div>`
});

Vue.component('comments', {
  data () {
    return {
      comments: [{ id: 124, text: 'fkgnsdklgnl' }, { id: 2135325, text: 'nlekng345gn' }]
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <div v-for="comment in comments" :key="comment.id">
      <comment :comment-object="comment" />
    </div>
  </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<comments />`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Very interesting insight, I dont really want to go down the SPA route with Vue, Id prefer to use angular if I was going to. I wanted to use vue as a kind of Jquery replacement, To get simple tasks done, Id read it was good for this, I dont know if im over complicating this in my mind at the moment being so new to it.

So for doing these drop ins it would be a case of the example under question 3, Would all of the vue "Apps" get placed in a single JS file (In my case i have app.js) or would I have multiple files eg comments.js which created that app included the components?

Comment: I have added an example. You can of course use Vue as a replacement for jQuery; then the above approach should fit. Keep in mind that Vue is a data driven framework compared to jQuery which targets directly DOM elements. In your scenario, I would create many small Vue components and put them into one file (later on, if the file increases in size, split it to multiple files). Otherwise you would have a lot of HTTP requests. These components would then always be included into your page and can then directly be used by a Vue app. If you define generic modules, you can reuse them on each page.

Comment: The benefit of this approach is that if you decide to later on switch to a fully fledged Vue SPA application, you can use reuse all of your components. Keep in mind that if you have smaller components, they are better to test and easier to understand. E.g. splitting `<comments>` and `<comment>` into two components lets you directly bind the text of each comment to an element whereas this would be more complicated if you have this binding within `<comments>` where you have the data in an array (you would need to keep track of the index, etc.)

Comment: Thats brilliant, That explains it perfectly, I think the biggest thing was me was realising that you can have <div id="app"> // Everything including static content here </div> and mix and mash components with the static content, Ive had a good play with it this morning and I think I have finally grasped it, Took alot longer than id like to admit.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, typically you'd use a Vue component to iterate and render out each comment (possibly as sub-components).
2. You can fetch the data from an API, or render it into your blade template for Vue to use (saves on an API call and having to set up an API endpoint if you don't already have one).
3. If you're using the Vue scaffolding that Laravel provides, then a Vue instance is initialised on any page where the app.js bundle is loaded and attached to an element with the ID `app`, if there is one. Inside this element Vue will parse any template directives and render any components that have been registered. So you could register additional components (e.g. ProductThings) to put into different blade templates.
4. As I mentioned above, Laravel creates a single Vue instance. There's nothing that stops you rendering out static content via blade into the `app` container, which Vue will leave as-is, between components which contain independant functionality.

Comment: Thankyou, You made me realise I can mix and mash static content and vue components within the main div id=app, Much appreciated!